# How to preserve items modified by Javascript on Postbacks

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have some panels that I am showing/hiding based on user selection in a drop down. Now there are several controls on the page that are causing a post back. So once a postback occurs after I hide my panels, again all panels are visible and my hidden panels are also shown.

Not sure how to retain the panels that were shown and hidden respectively on a postback.

Comment: Are you using asp classic (.aspx files)?

Comment: Yes..ASP.net .aspx pages

Answer (score 0):

Put your postback controls and which needs to be updated in UpdatePanel with update mode conditional to that your other code will not interfeear after postback.

Example:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updMain" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server" DefaultButton="lnkSave">
      .....
     </asp:Panel>
  </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Now when you update updMain it will update content inside this update panel only so other javascript modified attributes outside this panel will not affect.

Another way to preserve data is save in hidden  fields and on post back read HiddenField and  code based on your requirements.